# How to get selected bootstrap tab form selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I seem to be struggling with this one alot. Every example I can find online does not work.

What I am trying to  do is access a specific form inside the selected tab. But no matter what I try, onload the event doesn't run and does not pick the selected tab. You have to switch back and forth between a tab for the event to fire.

So my question is, if active tabs are set, how do I access the form element only in the visible or active tab?

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
    <form id="form1">

</form>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <form id="form2">

</form>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
  alert(target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The tab open with bootstrap will have the active class. In fact some js remove the active classe from the previous open tab and add it to the tab you've just open.

Therefore you can select it with `$(".active")`, and if you want your form for that particular tab `$(".active").find(".my-form")`

`$("#myTab").children(".active")` will only select the direct children of myTab which gave the active class if you want to be more specific

Comment: By specifying the active class only risks picking other active classes of any other navigation tabs on the page. How to make sure it picks up the form only for the current select navigation tab and not others that may exsist on the page?

Comment: $("#myTab").children(".active") will only select the direct children of myTab which gave the active class.